# Salesforce LWC nested for each loops with if condition

Tags: lightning-web-components, loop, lwc-dom, nested

I am trying to implement a listbox in LWC. The list box is showing values from a picklist in Account object. On click the value of the selected item is adding to an array. But on the UI it is not showing which objects are selected.

I want to compare two arrays and if the value is found in selected array the rendering should have a slds-focus class applied to the item else it should not. How can I compare the values in the selected array with picklist values array. I was trying the following code but its not working.

```
<template for:each={picklistvalues} for:item="item" >
        <template key={item} for:each={selectedSource} for:item="sitem" >
                <div if:true={item = sitem}>
                        <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" >
                                <div class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small" role="option">
                                        <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
                                        <span class="slds-media__body">
                                                <span id={item} title={item} onclick={handleSelect}>{item}</span>
                                        </span>
                                </div>
                        </li>
                </div>
        </template>     
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a different approach to compare the two arrays, such as using a JavaScript getter or a computed property, or you can refactor your HTML template to avoid nesting and conflicting directives.

For example, you can use the following code to compare the two arrays using a JavaScript getter and display them in a list with a check mark if they match or a cross mark if they don't:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <template for:each={matchedItems} for:item="item">
                <li key={item.value}>
                    {item.value} ==> {item.matched}
                </li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
    
export default class CompareArray extends LightningElement {
        @track array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
        @track array2 = ['A', 'E', 'C',];

        get matchedItems() {  
            return this.array1.map((value, index) => {
                    let matched = false;
                    this.array2.forEach(function(item) {
                        if(!matched){
                            matched = (value === item) ? true : false;
                        }
                    });
                    return {
                        value: value,
                        matched:  matched
                    };
                });
        }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: `get matchedItems() { return this.array1.map((value) => ({ value, matched: !!this.array2.find((value2) => value === value2)})); }`